# symfony postgres connection with custom schema does not work

Tags: postgresql, docker, symfony, dockerfile, doctrine

When using database_name.my_schema on a remote database it tells me that db does not exists, but if I use only the database_name it seems to connect, but when I run

`RUN php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction`

on Dockerfile it fails to connect.

On /config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    dbname : 'my_db' // or dbname.myschema
    user : 'user'
    password : 'xxxxxxxx'
    host : 'xxxxxxxx'
    port: 1520
    driver : 'pdo_pgsql'
    server_version: '13'
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-apache AS symfony_php

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libpq-dev libzip-dev git libxml2-dev wget --no-install-recommends \
  && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql zip \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/download/2.3.5/composer.phar \
  && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer


COPY docker/php/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini

COPY . /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www
RUN composer install

RUN php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction

RUN mkdir ./var/cache/pfv && mkdir ./var/log/pfv && chmod -R 777 ./var/cache && chmod -R 777 ./var/lo
```

So, the questions are what is the correct setup for postgres with custom schema and why when apparently it connects with just de database name, the migration command fails.

EDIT

Error thrown:

> [critical] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction". Message: "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired"
> In ExceptionConverter.php line 81:

An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired

Comment: Can we see your error please ? Have you properly encoded the passsord (URI encode) ?

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz I added the error to the question. For some reason it is unable to connect to the db when attempting to run migrations